# Парсинг и сортировка

Tags: java, android, xml, сортировка

Добрый вечер! Подскажите, пожалуйста, с такой задачей. Есть XML лист с погодными станциями, необходимо найти наименьшее расстояние:

```
<station>
<station_id>TAPA</station_id>
<latitude>17.117</latitude>
<longitude>-61.783</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TAPA.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
<station_id>TKPN</station_id>
<latitude>17.2</latitude>
<longitude>-62.583</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TKPN.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
<station_name>Blackburne/Plymouth</station_name>
<latitude>16.75</latitude>
<longitude>-62.167</longitude>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/TRPM.xml</xml_url>
</station>
```

После парсинга, получаю данные и задаю их на объекте Station, котрый выполняет Comparable, чтобы отсортировать по distance, которую я вычисляю зная latitude и longitute:

```
doInBackground(Void...params){
....

                Station station = null;

                double stationLatitude = 0;
                double stationLongitude = 0;
                String xml = null;
                double distance = 0;

                ArrayList<Station> data = new ArrayList<Station>();

                //прохожу по каждой станции в XML..
                for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength();i++){
                    currentItem = itemList.item(i);
                    //Log.i("Current Item: ", "" + currentItem.getNodeName());
                    itemChildren = currentItem.getChildNodes();

                    //..и создаю объект Station
                    station = new Station();
                    for (int j = 0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++){

                        currentChild = itemChildren.item(j);

                        if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("latitude")){


                            stationLatitude = Double.parseDouble(currentChild.getTextContent());

                            //Log.i("Latitude: ", "" + stationLatitude);

                            station.setLatitude(stationLatitude);

                        } else if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("longitude")){


                            stationLongitude = Double.parseDouble(currentChild.getTextContent());

                            //Log.i("Longitude: ", "" + stationLongitude);

                            station.setLongitude(stationLongitude);

                        } else if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("xml_url")){

                            xml = currentChild.getTextContent();

                           // Log.i("XML: ", "" + xml);

                            station.setUrl(xml);
                        }

                       //неадекватные значения после выхода из if/else:
                        Log.i("Latitude: ", "" + station.getLatitude());
                        Log.i("Longitude: ", "" + station.getLongitude());


                        distance = calcDistance(deviceLongitude, deviceLatitude, station.getLongitude(), station.getLatitude());


                        station.setDistance(distance);

                        data.add(station);

                    }

                }
                Collections.sort(data);


                Log.i("Наименьшее расстояние", "" + data.get(0).getDistance());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Т.е. в объект Station записываются неадекватные значения, даже если я их заранее в if/else записываю в объект:

```
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.762 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: -61.783
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: -61.783
02-21 13:30:10.772 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 17.117
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Latitude:: 0.0
02-21 13:30:10.782 29803-29843/com.andro.location I/Longitude:: 0.0
```

Когда доходит до сортировки, получаю Exception: "Comparison method violates its general contract!"

Comment: выведи в лог объект после парсинга, что в нем?

Comment: Кучу объектов с дубдирующимися значениями: http://i.imgsafe.org/4d6d38d.jpg

Comment: это если после циклов `Log.d("", "data: " + data);` ?

Comment: Да, внутри циклов все нормально. Поэтому я и подумал запихивать данные в объект сразу внутри цикла, но при выходу всё равно каша

Comment: как мне кажется, плохая идея создавать объект внутри цикла, после прохождения цикла по новой создается объект `station` и, что скорее всего, из-за этого значения получаются `0.0`

Comment: Да, понимаю, идея не очень, пока ничего не приходит в голову:/

Comment: а что мешает вынести создание объекта из цикла и добавить рядом с `ArrayList<Station> data = new ArrayList<Station>();` ?

Comment: Гениально, как я это пропустил)) Всё, вопрос снят, спасибо!!

Comment: добавлю это в ответ, отметь, если не сложно )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вынеси создание объекта `station` из цикла:

`ArrayList<Station> data = new ArrayList<Station>();
station = new Station();`